# How to convert number to width string property? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, width

I am trying to update the width of a div with a javascript variable but cannot understand how to format it properly.

This way works where you define a fixed percentage.

```
divider.style.width = '20%';
```

But I am unable to use a variable like this:

```
var progress = 40/100;
divider.style.width = progress;
```

Can anyone point out the proper way to format a float variable into a string that the width property will understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
divider.style.width = (progress * 100) + '%';
```